# Google Maps SDK can't verify API Key

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

This problem has been bothering me for a while and I can't figure out how to fix it. I've set the bundle identifier for the API key allowed iOS apps exactly as it in Xcode. I've tried changing my bundle ID and still nothing. If I add the demo app's bundle ID and test the demo app, it works just fine, but for some reason in my app, it fails no matter what I try to do. I've made sure to log the bundle ID using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];` and copying and pasting the id into the console and then copying and pasting the API key into the `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"APIKEYHERE"];` method. Still nothing works. I've looked all over stack overflow and the internet but I could find nothing that helps. I've followed the step by step instructions as per [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios) article but still nothing helps. When I run my app all I get is a blank screen with this console log message:

```
2014-05-18 01:43:31.761 MyApp[3249:a0b] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.8.0.8950
2014-05-18 01:43:32.615 MyApp[3249:4803] +[NSData gtm_dataByInflatingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x391f238
2014-05-18 01:43:32.618 MyApp[3249:a0b] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 101.)"
2014-05-18 01:43:32.804 MyApp[3249:5b07] +[NSData gtm_dataByInflatingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x391f238
2014-05-18 01:43:32.804 MyApp[3249:a0b] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 101.)"
2014-05-18 01:43:36.909 MyApp[3249:5b07] +[NSData gtm_dataByInflatingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x391f238
2014-05-18 01:43:36.909 MyApp[3249:a0b] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 101.)"
2014-05-18 01:43:45.020 MyApp[3249:5b07] +[NSData gtm_dataByInflatingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x391f238
2014-05-18 01:43:45.021 MyApp[3249:a0b] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 101.)"
2014-05-18 01:43:45.021 MyApp[3249:a0b] Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 101.)"
```

Please note that I am getting error code `101` not `100`. 100 is what I've seen on other similar questions.

Also I'd like to note my API is 39 characters not 40 as it says in the [documentation.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#obtaining_an_api_key)

Comment: Have you tried to delete the API key from the Google Console and remake a new API key? It happened to me once and I can only make it work by deleting and recreating. By the way, 1.8.0 is not stable as it crashed my app, already reported the bug to Google. Use 1.7.2 better.

Comment: @Ricky, yes I tried that too, but still nothing had worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it misses a category.. make sure you have -ObjC linker flag set for your app

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had changed that but I guess I didn't.